# How can I make a react native application with push notifications and an API

Tags: api, react-native, push-notification

I am building a new application in React Native and I built an API for the back-end.
I want to build in a push notification in the app when there is a new entry delivered by the API. I saw a framework that background fetches an API route and then shows a push notification but this only applies ones every 15 minutes. Other push notifications tutorials I see only work with a firebase database and I need it to work with my API.

Is somebody known with combining rest api's with push notifications in react native, that can help me?

Greetings,
Laurens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

step 1:- first you need to add react-native-firebase, messaging  in your react-native project for receiving push notification.

[link to add react-native-firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage)

step 2 :- check your application setup using firebase console's 
Cloud Messaging service.
https://console.firebase.google.com/project/fir-demo-f375c/notification
if your application setup is perfect you will get push notification in device from firebase console's Cloud Messaging service.

step 3:- need to add  server side code to fire push notification from server,
when your api hites to using server language like PHP.
for more detail in step 3 follow
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#implementing-http-connection-server-protocol

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. My first intention was to set up an API for my app was because I thought Firebase used different databases for different platforms. But now I see that I can combine them in one Firebase database and maybe don’t need an API to achieve this. Is this true and if yes would you recommend still using an API and why?

Comment: yes firebase's single database can be use for multiple platform,  which is firebase's database advantage. 

using PN, it depends on your app requirement. for eg. there is new entry (article or some reading material) by admin (using website), Now you want to send PN to all mobile users that there is new entry by admin , then use PN. or if you not use PN then when ever your users will open app then they can see new entry.

using an API and why ?
as mobile dev i have less backend exp. sending PN from backend if FireBase gives methods to send PN then use those methods, or use API

Comment: Thank you for helping me out and clearing things up! I still wonder why would people still use API's when Firebase can do everything for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Expo Server to push  notifications:
https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/overview/
or use FCM & APNs:
https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/sending-notifications-custom/

All the SDK here: https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/sending-notifications/